# Trouble trying to run queued Github Actions

Tags: github, continuous-deployment, github-actions, building-github-actions

I got a case where two GitHub Actions are running concurrently (as intended) with a push on master branch. Problem is, I want it to run in a queue instead and I couldn't find any helpful doc about it. In my case, I needed the action to only run after a run of the same action ends as my deploy breaks if its still executing the last one. I would have to deal with a third-party cli that I didn't want to in first place to make it wait instead of straight up deploying, I would very much prefer doing it on the whole action.

Comment: Do you *need* the actions to be separate? If you put them in separate jobs in the same workflow, you'd get the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see here the following solutions:

1. You can "sleep" your dependant workflow to simulate a waiting for
   1st workflow. [wait-action](https://github.com/jakejarvis/wait-action) might help
   you with that.
2. You can try to trigger second action from the first action (instead of trigger it on 
   `push`).

But all these options tbh are more like hacks. GitHub Actions are designed to run in parallel and if you want to run actions in specific order you should consider to use jobs instead and use `needs` property to make a dependency between them. Example:

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    name: Run 1st job
  job2:
    name: Run 2nd job
    needs: job1
```

Documentation - [needs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **concurrency**.

```
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

concurrency: ci

jobs:
```

[Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant two separate workflows. I use this one:

```
name: workflow-name
on:
  workflow_run:
    # this is the requisite workflow
    workflows: ["previous-workflow-name"]
    types:
      - completed
jobs:
  job1:
    # Runs the steps only if the previous-workflow-name workflow is successful
    # Doesn't mean it's completed then i'ts successfull
    # https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26238
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
```